# Collections.shuffle(array) inverse?

Tags: java

Is there any inverse function of `Collections.shuffle(List<?> list)` which is able to provide the value of the array from the result of `Collections.shuffle(List<?> list)` ?

Comment: What do you mean "value"?

Comment: There is no `Collections.shuffle` method taking an array, and shuffling a `List` randomizes the order of its elements, so there can hardly be any "inverse function".

Comment: I mean the array @AndyTurner

Comment: @user1893 you've got a reference to `array` already - you have just passed it into the method. I'm confused as to what you're asking.

Comment: @user1893 `Collections` package works on collections, not on arrays. Anyway you cannot reverse shuffle process. Store copy somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. The best you can do is create two arrays, one cloned from the other, then shuffle only one.

Comment: Hmm... By knowing that shuffling is implemented as Fisher-Yaffles algorithm and knowing that it uses Random which is a LCG with known parameters and knowing that Random uses current time as it seed value, I believe that it would be possible to reconstruct original array. But not until somebody offers $100K grant for that. :)

Comment: @gudok I mean, theoretically we can just shuffle continuously until it's in the original state, at some point it should shuffle correctly.

Comment: @gudok - that only works provided that the the implementations of Collections.shuffle and Random stay the same.  There are at least three "facts" that are not stated in the javadocs of the respective classes.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Collection.shuffle(Collection, Random) and create the random using a known seed, then you reshuffle a Collection with ordered ints with a new Random that has the same seed, so that you get the mapping:

```
long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();//A random seed
List<String> in = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h");

System.out.println("original: \t" + in);

Collections.shuffle(in, new Random(seed));
System.out.println("shuffled: \t" + in);

//Ordered list of integers from 0 to in.size()
List<Integer> mapping = IntStream.range(0, in.size()).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.shuffle(mapping, new Random(seed));//same seed -> same shuffle

String[] out = new String[in.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < out.length; i++)
    out[mapping.get(i)] = in.get(i);

System.out.println("out: \t\t" + Arrays.toString(out));
```

output:

```
original:   [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]
shuffled:   [f, h, c, e, d, g, a, b]
out:        [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]
```